# Is it useful to have a dedicated object for a lock?

Tags: java, synchronized

I am cleaning up a legacy java code and I found following construct:

```
final class QuiteComplexClass {
    private Object lock = new Object();

    void aMethod() {
        ...
        synchronized(lock) {
              ....
        }
    }
}
```

Is the special object for locking necessary here? What is difference when I used simple `synchronized (this)`?

I think it might by useful when the class is publicly visible and somebody may call `synchronized` on the class instance by mistake. But this class is package private so no external code can do that.

Comment: I'd make lock final too.

Comment: What's important is not that the `lock` is a dedicated object.  What's important is that it's a _private_ object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the special object for locking necessary here? What is difference when I used simple `synchronized (this)`?

Short answer: no, it's not necessary but aside from adding `final` I see little to no benefit to remove it.

I tend to like to use locking objects because they give me a more fine grained lock as opposed to locking on `this`.  You might have a couple different lock objects in your class if you are, for example, protecting multiple collections from race conditions.  One thing to sure is that you should always make sure to make the lock field `final`.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

This said, if a class is simple and you want to make sure people know which methods are `synchronized` then using the keyword on the methods is very appropriate as well.  As you mentioned, this is an internal class but even then, developers working on the outer class might want to know about the sync points.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that if you use `this` as lock or mark method as `synchronized` then another piece of code could accidentally (or intentionally) use your `QuiteComplexClass` object as a lock. And it might cause your code to work incorrectly. If some other developer decides to write the code as below then your code will not be able to call `synchronized` methods on `qcc` instance while lock is being held.

```
synchronized(qcc) { // assuming qcc is an instance of QuiteComplexClass
   while (true); // or any other time consuming operation
}
```

Comment: Backing up the above: see item 82 in Effective Java, 3rd. edition.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's unnecessary. Using a lock object is a pattern intended to avoid locking on the instance. Whether that is valuable often is a matter of opinion.